# issue with swiping a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I would like to do some stuff when a user swipes to the right of a UITableViewCell, so I use

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

However I tried to slide to the right and this didn't get invoked, why is this? All of my UITableView delegates are invoked.

I also have this in my code:

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     return YES;
 }


 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

All I want to do is to add a subview when a swipe happens

Comment: This is odd because I just tried the same thing and it calls when I swipe.  I'm sure you have, but you say you have set up your tableView delegate and dataSource to self already and put the tableView delegate and dataSource protocols in the header?  Nevermind that, I believe mackworth hit it on the nose

Comment: Its likely that you only set the data source and not the delegate.

Comment: I have set both the delegate and data source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this method to your tableView delegate methods:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
         if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
             // Delete the row from the data source.
             [self.listTableView beginUpdates];
...
```

I assume because your other delegate methods are being called that you included  in your .h file @interface line?  If using IB did you right click on the tableview and wire up delegate and dataSource?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: method?

To quote Apple:

```
Note: A swipe motion across a cell does not cause the display of a Delete button 
unless the table view's data source implements the 
tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: method.
```

And, deleting that method in my project also causes the willBeginEditing not to be called.

Comment: Have you put NSLog's in canEdit and willBeginEdit?  What happens if you programmatically go into editing mode (setEditing:animated)? Have you implemented tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: ? If so, what does it say, and how is it called?

Answer (score 1):

```
// You missed this?
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return YES;
}


- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return @"Remove";
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property of table view

```
tableView.editing = YES;
```

Comment: did you IBOutlet is connected properly??? make right as well as left swipe... and check whether it's working or not...